# Global variables claiming not declared

Tags: c++

I'm trying to globally declare a two dimensional array of pointers.

In global.h I have :

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

#include<vector>
#include "PlayerClass.h"
#include "MonsterClass.h"
#include "RoomClass.h"

void roomDeclare (int xSize, int ySize)
{
    RoomClass **room = new RoomClass*[xSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < xSize; i++) room[i] = new RoomClass[ySize];
}

...

#endif
```

and then in my main.cpp I have :

```
#include "global.h"


...

/*get maxX and maxY from player*/

roomDeclare(maxX, maxY);
MapGen(maxX, maxY, room, ...);
```

It's telling me that "error : room was not declared in this scope", it was clearly declared in global.h and that's included.

Comment: You are certainly unaware of the concept of "scope". You should learn it, as it's a fundamental language element.

Answer (score 2):

Variables defined inside a function are local to that function and they lose scope as soon as the function returns. You need to declare the room variable at the global level - not inside any function.

room should also be marked as `extern` in the header file and declared in a code file (either globals.cpp or main.cpp), else each code file which includes it will attempt to create it's own room, and will cause link errors, or incorrect behavior. Using `extern` ensures that all code files are referring to the same `room`.

You may also need to store the xSize as a global variable, or pass it to a function which will free up the memory allocated in roomDeclare, since you need to know the dimension of the array to clean it up properly.

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

#include <vector>
#include "PlayerClass.h"
#include "MonsterClass.h"
#include "RoomClass.h"

extern RoomClass** room;

void roomDeclare(int xSize, int ySize);

void roomFree();

#endif //GLOBAL_H
```

---

```
#include "global.h"

RoomClass** room;

void roomDeclare(int xSize, int ySize) {
    room = new RoomClass*[xSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < xSize; i++) {
        room[i] = new RoomClass[ySize];
    }
}

void roomFree(int xSize) {
    for (int i=0; i < xSize; i++) {
        delete [] room[i];
    }
    delete [] room;
}
```

---

In C++ you would not typically do this as it's easy to forget to clean up the memory. You would typically encapsulate this behavior into a class, where the room pointer is a private member of the class, allocation happens in the class constructor, freeing happens in the destructor. You would expose the rooms through class methods in a way that they don't modify the room object itself, to prevent memory leaks, and to keep code tidy and maintainable.

Comment: I'll use extern in the declaration, but how do I declare it globally instead of inside the scope of the function?

Comment: I've done what is in the second snippet, but it's claiming "error : RoomClass does not name a type" I have included "RoomClass.h" in global.h.

Also, in the second snippet, why do you have #include "global.h", shouldn't that be in global.h?

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing the error. As for where to define room, it does not want to be in globals.h - the extern declaration for it is in global.h, but it's actual definition needs to be placed in a code file such that it is only compiled once. Also, header files are generally there for declaring function prototypes, but it's best to have them implemented in code files, or you may end up with duplicate implementations in the compiled program (wasted space, etc).

Answer (score 1):

The scope of room is limited to the funciont roomDeclare().  It is not visible in the global namespace where you are trying to use it.  You can declare it above roomDeclare() and populate it inside the function.